# Investigate influence of two parameters to the number of solutions of the system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra

Investigate for what values of $λ$ and $μ$ the system of equations
$x+y+z=6$,
$x+2y+3z=10$,
$x+2y+λz=μ$
has a) No solutions
      b) Infinite number of solutions
      c)  Unique solution

How to do this question with Augmented Matrix method can somebody please explain fast I have a test in 4 hours :(

My row echelon form is coming 
$\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & 1 & 6 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 10 \\ 
1 & 2 & \lambda & \mu 
\end{array}
\right]$

Comment: Hint: If all variables are pivot variables, then there is a unique solution.  If there are free variables, but the system is consistent, there are infinitely many solutions.  If there are free variables and the system is inconsistent, then there are no solutions.

Comment: @MichaelBurr  My row echelon form is coming
 [ 1 1 1 | 6 ]
 [ 0 1 2 | 4 ]
 [ 0 0 λ-3 | μ-10 ]

How to proceed from this?

Comment: @DivyamKhanna Use Michael Burr's hint. (If λ-3 is nonzero, then there is a unique solution. If λ-3=0, and μ-10=0, then there are infinitely many solutions. If λ-3=0, but μ-10 is nonzero, then there are no solutions.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & 1 & 6 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 10 \\ 
1 & 2 & \lambda & \mu 
    \end{array}
\right]\sim\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & 1 & 6 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 10 \\ 
0 & 0 & \lambda-3 & \mu-10 
    \end{array}
\right]\sim\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & 1 & 6 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 & 4 \\ 
0 & 0 & \lambda-3 & \mu-10 
    \end{array}
\right]$

For $\lambda\neq 3$ this will have a unique solution for all $\mu$, as we can reduce the matrix into $I$ and thus find the solution on the right side of the augmented matrix.

For $\lambda=3$ and $\mu=10$, then there are infinitely many (the last row is completely $0$, just look what happens in the system of equations). If $\mu\neq 10$, there are no solutions, again take a look at the system of equations.

Comment: I would suggest using a condition other than the last row being all $0$'s to imply that there are infinitely many solutions.  This rule only applies to square systems (and students all too frequently use this condition in an over-determined system).  Perhaps, instead point out that there are no false statements and there is a free variable.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Well, that's pretty much what I meant with looking at the underlying system of equations.